# How to use SpatialOperator in filter expression in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, filter, expression

In a python script I want to specify a request filter expression using a spatial operator. I am following the general syntax "field name" operator condition. For example:

```
setFilterExpression('$geometry soOverlaps QgsRectangle(...)')
```

This gives no results and no error.

Please can somebody provide an example on how to build a valid expression using these spatial operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression editor shows a completely different syntax for the overlaps function:

> overlaps function
>
> Returns 1 if the geometries share space, are of the same dimension, but are not completely contained by each other. 
>   Syntax
>
> ```
>   overlaps( a, b )
> ```
>
> Arguments
>
> ```
> a → geometry b → geometry
> ```
>
> Example
>
> ```
> overlaps( geomFromWKT( 'LINESTRING(3 5 , 4 4 , 5 5 , 5 3)'  ) , geomFromWKT( 'LINESTRING(3 3 , 4 4 , 5 5)' ))   → returns 1
> overlaps( geomFromWKT( 'LINESTRING(0 0 , 1 1)'  ) , geomFromWKT( 'LINESTRING(3 3 , 4 4 , 5 5)' ))    → returns 0
> ```